# gets_s() expected behavior

Tags: c, language-lawyer

**tl;dr**

Is it a constraint violation if the next new-line character is the `n`th character in `stdin`?

---

Implementing [gets_s()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets), I was wondering about what I consider to be a contradiction in the standard's wording.

The standard's definition (Annex K) reads (emphasis mine):

> `char *gets_s(char *s, rsize_t n);`
>
> Runtime-constraints
>
> [...] **A new-line character**, end-of-file, or read error **shall occur within reading
> n-1 characters** from `stdin`.

> [...]
>
> The `gets_s` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n`
> from the stream pointed to by `stdin`, into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional
> characters are read after a new-line character (which is discarded) or after end-of-file.
> **The discarded new-line character does not count towards number of characters read.**

Let us assume that a new-line character appears as the `n`th character of the input. The clearest example would be with `n == 1` and the next character in the `stdin` stream being that new-line.

Am I expected to...

- ...consider this a constraint violation (no newline within `n - 1 == 0` chracters read from `stdin`)? This would mean a call to the constraint violation handler, and returning `NULL`.
- ...reading the newline, discarding it (and not counting it towards the number of characters read), and returning `s`?

Either case would see `s[0] = '\0'`, and (everything up to and including) the newline read / discarded from `stdin`.

Comment: @AdrianMole: As the rest of the standard handles the issue of buffering transparently, and the buffering of the stream could be `_IOFBF` just as well as `_IOLBF` or `_IONBF`, I see no reason to assume that this function's definition suddenly plays games with what is "read" and what is "processed".

Comment: @AdrianMole: Well, there is the first sentence of my first quote block, contradicting that last sentence of my second quote block. *That is the question at hand.* Unless you feel there is something unclear to my question, feel free to try your hand at an actual answer... (No offense intended, I just get the impression that you are *insinuating* an answer in a comment here.)

Comment: @AdrianMole But `new-line character does not count towards number of characters read.` when `gets_s` reads the `<newline>` after `abc`, the count of read characters stays at 3, because newline does not count. This is exactly the question. Because for `char b[4]; gets(b)` giving `abc\n` as input is fine.

Comment: The first part of the standard quote states that no newline in the first n-1 (!!) characters is a constraint violation (failed call). That is the contradiction. I totally agree that your *interpretation* makes sense (n being the buffer size, so there would be space for n-1 characters plus a zero terminator). So we have a "bug" in the standard's wording? That is an answer, not a comment trying to clarify the question.

Comment: Whether the *variable* `n` changes in the scope of the `gets_s` function is an irrelevant implementation detail. *My* implementation counts it down, because I don't believe in spawning local loop counters unless necessary, and I don't need the original value of `n` at the end of the function (as opposed to the original value of `s`).

Comment: Shouldn't it simply work in the same way as `fgets`? In fact, isn't it just a wrapper function calling `fgets(..., stdin)` internally?

Comment: @Lundin No. fgets() does not check for runtime constraints, does not drop excessive input to sync number of calls to number of lines, does not drop the line-end...

Comment: Ah I see, gets_s removes \n from stdin as opposed to fgets. I have never used these peculiar bounds-checking functions before.

Comment: @Lundin I had not originally considered them for implementation either, but strtok_s turned out to be a viable solution for a downstream problem without me having to go into *POSIX* extensions, so I went for Annex K, and I'd like to go "either full support or none". Only four more functions to go. Uunfortunately the backends to printf() and scanf() are among them. :-D

Comment: Somewhat related to this question, I just stumbled upon this this [DR 429](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm#dr_429) which you might find interesting. Apparently a proposed fix to `gets_s` was rolled out with C17.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, the wording left something to be desired. It was rather self-explanatory though (the footnote made it clear that a line of input should be consumed for each call to `gets_s`, whether successful or not -- and I am not in the habit of writing to  NULL[0]). Thanks for the heads-up, though; good to see they will clean that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reasoning would be `gets_s` is a safe version for `gets`. When `char b[4]; gets(b)` then reading `abc\n` and `abc<eof>` is fine, then I would assume `gets_s(b, 4)` should also be fine. From [K.1p5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.1p5): `The alternative functions verify that output buffers are large enough for the intended result and return a failure indicator if they are not.`

I believe your reasoning is correct. Because `discarded new-line character does not count towards number of characters read` it doesn't count against the "read n-1 characters from stdin". However I think the wording is off.

The [microsoft documentation gets_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/gets-s-getws-s?view=msvc-160) is worded a bit different:

> [...] if the buffer is too small to contain the input line  [...] these functions invoke an invalid parameter handler

---

> consider this a constraint violation (no newline within n - 1 == 0 chracters read from stdin)?

No.

> reading the newline, discarding it (and not counting it towards the number of characters read), and returning s?

Yes.

Comment: An additional tidbit: Even if the `n`'th character read is *not* a new-line, you don't have to "ungetc" it, because the handling of the constraint violation requires you to read on (without writing into `s`) until you *do* encounter a new-line. That realization cleared things up further to me.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to analyse the second quote first, especially:

> The discarded new-line character does not count towards number of
> characters read.

This means, in my (quite fluent) comprehension of the English language that, for a given `n` value (buffer size) of `4` and an input of `abc\n`, then, when the newline is 'encountered' (or *parsed* or *processed* - whatever specific verb you prefer), the number of characters that have been read is `3` (which is `n-1`).

Thus, referring back to the first quote:

> ...shall occur within reading n-1 characters

we can say (definitively) that a newline *has occurred* (yet another option for that verb) within reading `n-1` characters.

The same applies to your `n == 1` case: a newline occurs when `0` characters have been read.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a constraint violation if the next new-line character is the nth character in stdin?

As I see it: no.

---

OP's does well lay out the potentially conflicting/unclear specifications.

Yet step back to what `gets_s()` is to do, replace `gets()`.

In the case of input `"123\n"`, both below functions should work well with no *undefined behavior* (UB) nor constraint violation.

```
char s[4];
gets(s);
gets_s(s, sizeof s);
```

---

IOWs, if input does not cause UB with `gets()`, same input should not cause a constraint violation with `gets_s()`.

If the spec is unclear/differ on that point, it should change.

OTOH, `gets_s()` of Annex K may not survive the next release.